# Is the kid a reference to another Marvel hero?

Tags: iron-man-3, marvel-cinematic-universe, comic-adaptation

The kid Harley Keener played a pretty important role in Iron Man 3.  To me it sort of seemed that the movie was hinting that he was going to be another hero, maybe from the Iron Man universe, maybe from the general Marvel universe.

Am I reading too much into this, or is the kid suposed to be important outside just this movie?

Comment: I suspect if he was going to have any greater role he'd be an established Marvel character... a quick google suggests he isn't.  I'm not sure this is a question which has an answer at this time.

Comment: @liath i did some rudimentary search and didn't turn up anything.  That doesn't mean they didnt' change the name to be sneaky (like in dark knight rises)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I only commented - I don't feel qualified to answer this one!

Comment: Again, with no concrete evidence to support an answer, we can merely speculate. That said, I don't think he is anything more than a plot device.

Comment: @nobby i have a knack for asking hard to answer questions...

Comment: What if the reference to Harley Keener, is a way of introducing another character from a different part of Marvel Comics? Beatrix Keener is Coachwhip. Could there be a link?

Comment: Or possibly the link could be the following, that Harvey Keener is a reference to Harley Davis aka Motormouth?

Comment: Harley Davis is female and marvel UK's superhero.

Comment: Iron Lad is a possibility but doesn't he eventually become kang the conqueror?

Comment: Purely speculation but we have seen in the agents of shield and the item 47 one shot shield like to pick up strays who have interacted with the universe and have useful skills inspired by stark harley could get picked up and work for shield in a role that may benefit stark in future films ie. an engineer or mechanic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Harley's entry is just like Marvel's trend of copying from DC. As in *Dark Knight Rises* there is a new sidekick (new Robin), similarly Harley can be a future Iron-Man (or a mechanic :P).

As per my knowledge and Google search there is no Marvel's Character which matches with the movie's Harley. But as per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ty_Simpkins)

> Ty Simpkins has signed a 3 picture deal for Marvel Studios in an
>   unspecified role.

This makes the possibility for expedition of character in Marvel cinematic universe. So we could wait and see if something else hidden in the character.

Comment: -ve vote, most probably from Downey.:P

Answer (score 7):

To answer simply, no, the kid is not based on any existing Marvel characters before. However, I believe the character was added by Disney to make the film more kid-friendly, to have a character that children can identify with. If I was not mistaken, at the time of the release, the character was poorly received, as with Mandarin's different take (an image, rather than a real terrorist.) another edit perceived to be done by Disney.